# View ASPX page in Web browser

Tags: asp.net

I have the following .aspx page, and I want to view it in web browsers such as IE or Google Chrome by opening it directly in those browsers:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But somehow the browsers can't render it. In IE, the error is

> Cannot view XML input using XSL style
>   sheet. Please correct the error and
>   then click the Refresh button, or try
>   again later. A name was started with
>   an invalid character. Error processing
>   resource 'file:/

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#"AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %> -^*
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove or comment out the

<`%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>`

line as a browser doesn't know what to do with it.  This is normally interpreted by iis and not sent to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

It won't actually work properly unless it is "served" by a web server of some sort.

If you are using Visual Studio, fire up the debugger, which by default will open IE, then grab the url from the location bar, and paste that into the browsers you want to check. Elsewise, mount the web site in IIS, and browse it that way.

Just opening the source file in a browser probably won't give you the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Recent Visual Studios (at least 2010+) have a new feature called **View in Browser** which you can run on an *.aspx* file. Please note that, as per [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/df5x06h3(v=vs.110).aspx), debugging breakpoints are not in effect even if debugging is enabled.

Right click the file in the *Solution Explorer* or the *Editor* and then select View In Browser (your default browser here).

Keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>